Would it be possible to start a new town in America with its own political system?
How feasible would it be to start a town in the US where instead of mayors, senators and other legislator bodies, they use software and popular vote?
With everything coming down to popular vote, it should be based on some phone app that would verify a citizens identification and allow them to vote on all legislation.
Is there any federal law that would prohibit such a town?
If it got big enough would it actually be able to integrate with federal legislation?

In the US, towns exist within states and counties and are neither sanctioned nor prohibited by federal law. Perhaps you could [edit] the Q to make it more clear.

It wouldn't be feasible even if it was legal. Anyone trying would swiftly learn that it isn't a workable way to operate a local government.

"Can we vote for not paying the town's electricity and server bill?" - Can anyone hear me?

Are you talking about things which are within the competence of local government, like local taxation, education, planning, etc, rather than things which state or federal government control? Most towns don't actually pass much legislation, and a lot of decisions are made by council officials rather than votes.

Would benefit from some preliminary research. Cities are usually subunits of existing counties, which are subdivisions of states. Local decision-making gets layered on top of county and statewide requirements; generally anyone living in the city is also voting in county, state and federal elections by the mechanisms set up by those jurisdictions.

Obligatory xkcd. The idea of voting via your smartphone is a security nightmare, but just because it's a terrible idea doesn't mean it's not legal!

@ohwilleke It's technically legal; several groups actually tried, and they all found out exactly that pretty quick.

@jeffronicus "Cities are usually subunits of existing counties"  False, "Cities are usually . . . subdivisions of states." True.

The answer is a qualified yes.
The requirements to do so, and the procedures for doing so, vary state to state because (in the US anyway) cities and towns are basically sub-departments of the  state they exist within.
The process you describe, while a highly unusual take on the matter, is essentially a Town Meeting that never ends (or, to be compatible with existing structures that allow for Town Meetings, a meeting begins and ends each day - your hypothetical app would need to produce minutes of what the results of each vote were, etc.)
As with many things legal/political, just because you can doesn't mean you should. The history of Grafton, NH is one of many cautionary tales of town governments being formed as political experiments rather than for convenience of governance over locally salient issues such as provision of services and whatnot.
Its ability to integrate with Federal laws and regulations is not a function of its size, instead it's a pre-requirement for the town to exist for any appreciable length of time.  Certain matters, such as the administration of national elections and whatnot, would be subject to State laws and inescapably conducted according therewith.
Nothing within the town could violate or contradict either Federal or State law (Supremacy Clause, etc.) but beyond those basics - for better or worse (as Grafton highlights) - the town would be free to conduct business in the manner you describe assuming you could get it formed per the laws of the state you decided to attempt this within.

Grafton IIRC from reading the booking wasn't founded.  Its existing governance structure, such as it was, was merely coopted by a move-in from Libertarians from out of town and it devolved into a fairly humorous mess.  That aside this seems to answer the question well enough.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Edited slightly to clarify, you're correct.  Now reads "town governments" rather than towns.

I don't know if it's true across the whole US, but where I live, elections are a county responsibility, and cities and towns don't have much to do with administering them (sometimes they provide space for polling places, and of course their charters/ordinances/etc might specify what positions and measures need to be voted on)

@ThePhoton Election administration is a state government function. It is common for that to be handled at the county level, but not all cities and towns are within counties, there's unincorporated land, etc.  So there's variance and room for niche policies as the OP suggests. Moreover, many cities and towns have to have their own elections as their municipal governments are elected and/or involve referenda

@WilliamWalkerIII, unincorporated land is typically part of a county but not a city, not the other way around. And, at least in my region, elections for city offices (mayor, city council) and referenda are still administered by the county government (registrar of voters). The city doesn't hold separate elections, they just get the county to put their offices/issues on the ballot in the appropriate precincts.

I know there are special cases of cities that aren't part of counties. Presumably they have to provide many, many functions that are typically run by counties --- not just elections but also jails, courts, court bailiffs, evictions, etc.,

Starting a new town is relatively easy so long as the residents and existing locality agrees. I think you'd have no problem there. There are even states with lots of unincorporated land where you could just form your own town without chipping away at another.
But it's possible courts would look a bit askance at the phone app idea, because the Equal Protection Clause of the 14th Amendment has been found to apply to local governments as well as state ones. In other words, local governments cannot deny certain rights to some residents that it gives to other ones, at least not without very good reason.
If your scenario, you've effectively limited the franchise only to those with Internet connections and who own smart phones. You would probably need a workaround to ensure that those who lack the means to vote that way can vote in-person.
Otherwise I think the answer here is "there ain't no law," at least not on the federal level. It's possible individual states have laws that would throw a spanner in the works.

Most states have laws that will throw a spanner in the works: state law tends to prescribe the permitted forms of city government.

Internet connection is easy - plenty of places have free public WiFi. Arguably might not even need it to work in the entire town since in other places voting has to be done at designated places, but free WiFi in the entire incorporated area is an easy fix. As far as devices, that is easy too. In many places libraries provide free computer usage to everyone, so there could either be fixed voting devices in specified locations or a group purchase of limited use devices for those who can't/won't use their own.

@Mark That sounds it's worth its own answer!

There's still a significant difference in access between people who can vote on their phones anywhere at any time vs. those who have to physically visit the library at a time when nobody else is using their limited number of computers/voting machines.  Especially if votes are occurring daily or even weekly.  Possibly manageable if you also distribute free smartphones to anyone of voting age; less so otherwise.

Thank you for bringing up the Equal Protection Clause. Smartphone voting could also fall afoul of the Voting Rights Act (or what's left of it) and Americans With Disabilities Act. Not to mention the security nightmare of online voting.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact You're still requiring people to have a smartphone or other appliance to connect to WiFi with. And that that WiFi is secure.

@Shadur-don't-feed-the-AI As I said, devices could be provided for those who need them (or who don't want to use their own for whatever reason). Security and other things can be handled. Not trivial, but can be done.
